# Laravel 5.3 how to attach file

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm having difficulties in attaching file using Mailable in Laravel 5.3, I have folder resides in public folder 'attachment'. it always threw exception

`ErrorException' with message 'Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Message::attach() must be of the type array`

but in laravel5.3 docs it says `->attach('/path/to/file');`

```
    namespace App\Mail;



use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class PoattachmentEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
     public function __construct()
    {
       //
    }
public function build()
{
    $subject = 'Attention';

    return $this->view('emails.myview')
         ->attach(URL::to('/attachment/'.'newdata.xls'))
         ->subject($subject);
}
```

**vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailable.php**

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Mail;

use ReflectionClass;
use ReflectionProperty;
use BadMethodCallException;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Factory as Queue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer as MailerContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable as MailableContract;

class Mailable implements MailableContract
{
    /**
     * The person the message is from.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $from = [];

    /**
     * The "to" recipients of the message.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $to = [];

    /**
     * The "cc" recipients of the message.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $cc = [];

    /**
     * The "bcc" recipients of the message.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $bcc = [];

    /**
     * The "reply to" recipients of the message.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $replyTo = [];

    /**
     * The subject of the message.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $subject;

    /**
     * The view to use for the message.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $view;

    /**
     * The plain text view to use for the message.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $textView;

    /**
     * The view data for the message.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $viewData = [];

    /**
     * The attachments for the message.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $attachments = [];

    /**
     * The raw attachments for the message.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $rawAttachments = [];

    /**
     * The callbacks for the message.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $callbacks = [];

    /**
     * Send the message using the given mailer.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer  $mailer
     * @return void
     */
    public function send(MailerContract $mailer)
    {
        Container::getInstance()->call([$this, 'build']);

        $mailer->send($this->buildView(), $this->buildViewData(), function ($message) {
            $this->buildFrom($message)
                 ->buildRecipients($message)
                 ->buildSubject($message)
                 ->buildAttachments($message)
                 ->runCallbacks($message);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Queue the message for sending.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Factory  $queue
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function queue(Queue $queue)
    {
        $connection = property_exists($this, 'connection') ? $this->connection : null;

        $queueName = property_exists($this, 'queue') ? $this->queue : null;

        if ($queueName) {
            return $queue->connection($connection)->pushOn(
                $queueName, new SendQueuedMailable($this)
            );
        } else {
            return $queue->connection($connection)->push(
                new SendQueuedMailable($this)
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deliver the queued message after the given delay.
     *
     * @param  \DateTime|int  $delay
     * @param  Queue  $queue
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function later($delay, Queue $queue)
    {
        $connection = property_exists($this, 'connection') ? $this->connection : null;

        $queueName = property_exists($this, 'queue') ? $this->queue : null;

        if ($queueName) {
            return $queue->connection($connection)->laterOn(
                $queueName, $delay, new SendQueuedMailable($this)
            );
        } else {
            return $queue->connection($connection)->later(
                $delay, new SendQueuedMailable($this)
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Build the view for the message.
     *
     * @return array|string
     */
    protected function buildView()
    {
        if (isset($this->view, $this->textView)) {
            return [$this->view, $this->textView];
        } elseif (isset($this->textView)) {
            return ['text' => $this->textView];
        } else {
            return $this->view;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Build the view data for the message.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function buildViewData()
    {
        $data = $this->viewData;

        foreach ((new ReflectionClass($this))->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC) as $property) {
            if ($property->getDeclaringClass()->getName() != self::class) {
                $data[$property->getName()] = $property->getValue($this);
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Add the sender to the message.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Message  $message
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function buildFrom($message)
    {
        if (! empty($this->from)) {
            $message->from($this->from[0]['address'], $this->from[0]['name']);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add all of the recipients to the message.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Message  $message
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function buildRecipients($message)
    {
        foreach (['to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'replyTo'] as $type) {
            foreach ($this->{$type} as $recipient) {
                $message->{$type}($recipient['address'], $recipient['name']);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the subject for the message.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Message  $message
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function buildSubject($message)
    {
        if ($this->subject) {
            $message->subject($this->subject);
        } else {
            $message->subject(Str::title(Str::snake(class_basename($this), ' ')));
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add all of the attachments to the message.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Message  $message
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function buildAttachments($message)
    {
        foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) {
            $message->attach($attachment['file'], $attachment['options']);
        }

        foreach ($this->rawAttachments as $attachment) {
            $message->attachData(
                $attachment['data'], $attachment['name'], $attachment['options']
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Run the callbacks for the message.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Message  $message
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function runCallbacks($message)
    {
        foreach ($this->callbacks as $callback) {
            $callback($message->getSwiftMessage());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the priority of this message.
     *
     * The value is an integer where 1 is the highest priority and 5 is the lowest.
     *
     * @param  int  $level
     * @return $this
     */
    public function priority($level = 3)
    {
        $this->callbacks[] = function ($message) use ($level) {
            $message->setPriority($level);
        };

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the sender of the message.
     *
     * @param  object|array|string  $address
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function from($address, $name = null)
    {
        return $this->setAddress($address, $name, 'from');
    }

    /**
     * Set the recipients of the message.
     *
     * @param  object|array|string  $address
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function to($address, $name = null)
    {
        return $this->setAddress($address, $name, 'to');
    }

    /**
     * Set the recipients of the message.
     *
     * @param  object|array|string  $address
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function cc($address, $name = null)
    {
        return $this->setAddress($address, $name, 'cc');
    }

    /**
     * Set the recipients of the message.
     *
     * @param  object|array|string  $address
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function bcc($address, $name = null)
    {
        return $this->setAddress($address, $name, 'bcc');
    }

    /**
     * Set the "reply to" address of the message.
     *
     * @param  object|array|string  $address
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function replyTo($address, $name = null)
    {
        return $this->setAddress($address, $name, 'replyTo');
    }

    /**
     * Set the recipients of the message.
     *
     * @param  object|array|string  $address
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @param  string  $property
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function setAddress($address, $name = null, $property = 'to')
    {
        if (is_object($address) && ! $address instanceof Collection) {
            $address = [$address];
        }

        if ($address instanceof Collection || is_array($address)) {
            foreach ($address as $user) {
                $user = $this->parseUser($user);

                $this->{$property}($user->email, isset($user->name) ? $user->name : null);
            }
        } else {
            $this->{$property}[] = compact('address', 'name');
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Parse the given user into an object.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return object
     */
    protected function parseUser($user)
    {
        if (is_array($user)) {
            return (object) $user;
        } elseif (is_string($user)) {
            return (object) ['email' => $user];
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Set the subject of the message.
     *
     * @param  string  $subject
     * @return $this
     */
    public function subject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the view and view data for the message.
     *
     * @param  string  $view
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return $this
     */
    public function view($view, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->viewData = $data;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the plain text view for the message.
     *
     * @param  string  $textView
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return $this
     */
    public function text($textView, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->textView = $textView;
        $this->viewData = $data;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the view data for the message.
     *
     * @param  string|array  $key
     * @param  mixed   $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function with($key, $value = null)
    {
        if (is_array($key)) {
            $this->viewData = array_merge($this->viewData, $key);
        } else {
            $this->viewData[$key] = $value;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Attach a file to the message.
     *
     * @param  string  $file
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return $this
     */
    public function attach($file, array $options = [])
    {
        $this->attachments[] = compact('file', 'options');

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Attach in-memory data as an attachment.
     *
     * @param  string  $data
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return $this
     */
    public function attachData($data, $name, array $options = [])
    {
        $this->rawAttachments[] = compact('data', 'name', 'options');

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be called with the Swift message instance.
     *
     * @param  callable  $callback
     * @return $this
     */
    public function withSwiftMessage($callback)
    {
        $this->callbacks[] = $callback;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Dynamically bind parameters to the message.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return $this
     *
     * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
            return $this->with(Str::snake(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
        }

        throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist on mailable.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird, have you checked the method in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Message.php` ? I have the following definition `public function attach($file, array $options = [])`  which is ok (second parameter is optional). I have Laravel 5.2 but this shouldn't have changed though

Comment: Even in Laravel 5.4 this is preserved : https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Mail/Message.php

Comment: Though you can send a second parameter as an empty array but still weird and awaiting your answer regarding the method signature in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Message.php`

Comment: @ka_lin, it exist also in Mailable.php, I am confuse.

Comment: Have you updated Laravel by any chance or this is a fresh start?

Comment: @ka_lin, yes I also see that in Message.php, which one I use  use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable; or use Illuminate\Mail\Message;?

Comment: ok I will try to update I'll be back

Comment: @ka_lin, I updated but unfortunately still I get exception

Comment: Is `build()` a method within a controller?

Comment: @ka_lin, No I'm not in controller , it is inside in Mail folder, when we create php artisan make:mail

Comment: @ka_lin see https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#generating-mailables

Comment: @ka_lin, I updated my question

Comment: Please check the Mailable class, I can see that the second parameter is optional -> https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php . Try with an empty array (but it's still an issue) but you should debug (check if Mailable.php method is defined as on the github etc)

Comment: @ka_lin, yeah I did not put second parameter on it

Comment: Have you tried: `->attach(url('/attachment/'.'newdata.xls'));` ? Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-url

Comment: @ka_lin, yeah no luck!

Comment: Have you checked the Mailable's method `view()` (it should return $this) and the method `attach()` should have the second parameter optional - `array $options = []` )?

Comment: @ka_lin, I post the Mailable class

Comment: In this case...have you tried a priest?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are giving an object and it's expecting array